# Video driver for HP DL380 G6 for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, hp, hp-proliant, drivers

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 w/GUI on an HP DL380 G6 I found lying around - it has an ATI ES1000 graphics chip.

After install the screen is very 'laggy' and only 1024 resolution (I have 1280 monitor).

I believe I have tried the community/RadeonDriver but it reports 'llvmpipe' which indicates no 3D acceleration.

- How to get the video to work properly at the supported 1280 resolution?
- How to switch to 2D in Ubuntu 14.04? (not same as 12.04)
- Or, should I just install 14.04 Server and be done with it?

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to rely on the video capabilities of a rackmount server like this... Is there a chance that this is unique to the Ubuntu version? Did this work well with a previous OS?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was some Redhat server on there before - in console mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chip on this server (and most others) is *very* weak and will not support a GUI even with a proper graphics driver. For reference, it has 64 MB of video memory and 0 pixel/vertex shader support (which means no 3D acceleration).

These chips were only meant for console work. Install Server. The server will thank you for it.

Comment: Point taken. I was hoping to see what Ubuntu 14.04 looked like... wrong computer to do it on...

I have installed 14.04 server and it seems to work OK.
Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

It's a server, you're not supposed to have a GUI on it, especially not something like unity which really won't work on a weak old ati chip. If you must have an Ubuntu-ish gui, try xubuntu. But really, use SSH.

Comment: I was expecting too much from its graphics! 
I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 Server and it seems OK.

My lesson is learned - run servers in console mode. Don't even waste time trying to get a GUI up.